# Copying 100 GB with continues change of file between datacenters with R-sync is good idea?

Tags: rsync

I have a datacenter A which has 100GB of the file changing every millisecond. I need to copy and place the file in Datacenter B. In case of failure on Datacenter A, I need to utilize the file in B. As the file is changing every millisecond does r-sync can handle it at 250 miles far datacenter? Is there any possibility of getting the corropted file? As it is continuously updating when we call this as a finished file in datacenter B ?

Answer (score 1):

rsync is a relatively straightforward file copying tool with some very advanced features. This would work great for files and directory structures where change is less frequent.

If a single file with 100GB of data is changing every millisecond, that would be a potential data change rate of 100TB per second. In reality I would expect the change rate to be much smaller.

Although it is possible to resume data transfer and potentially partially reuse existing data, rsync is not made for continuous replication at that interval. rsync works on a file level and is not as commonly used as a block-level replication tool. However there is an --inplace option. This may be able to provide you the kind of file synchronization you are looking for. https://superuser.com/questions/576035/does-rsync-inplace-write-to-the-entire-file-or-just-to-the-parts-that-need-to

When it comes to distance, the 250 miles may result in at least 2ms of additional latency, if accounting for the speed of light, which is not all that much. In reality this would be more due to cabling, routers and switches.

rsync by itself is probably not the right solution. This question seems to be more about physics, link speed and business requirements than anything else. It would be good to know the exact change rate, and to know if you're allowed to have gaps in your restore points. This level of reliability may require a more sophisticated solution like log shipping, storage snapshots, storage replication or some form of distributed storage on the back end.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

No, rsync is probably not the right way to keep the data in sync based on your description.

100Gb of data is of no use to anybody without without the means to maintain it and extract information. That implies structured elements such as records and indexes. Rsync knows nothing about this structure therefore cannot ensure that writes to the file will transition from one valid state to another. It certainly cannot guarantee any sort of consistency if the file will be concurrently updated at either end and copied via rsync

Rsync might be the right solution, but it is impossible to tell from what you have said here.

If you are talking about provisioning real time replication of a database for failover purposes, then the best method is to use transaction replication at the DBMS tier. Failing that, consider something like drbd for block replication but bear in mind you will have to apply database crash recovery on the replicated copy before it will be usable at the remote end.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.